# Graph theory book for beginners

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, books

I need a book recommendation for graph theory which supposes background in set theory. I want to cover those questions first as graph theory is part of combinatorics. Can you recommend me a book which is beginner-friendly without going much into combinatorics?

I heard about Harris and West but these books use too much combinatorics. I want to do them later. I am self-studying, therefore asking this question.

Comment: Check out the book by Diestel. If that looks too scary, you could try picking up some more general book on discrete math which covers graphs only partly.

Comment: A basic fact about graphs is that the complete graph on $n$ vertices contains $\binom{n}{2}$ edges. This suggests that rejecting classical combinatorics would make it hard to do much graph theory.